# Remove value from array within post meta ajax admin

Tags: plugins, ajax, wp-admin, admin

I have an array within the post meta for a post. I want to be able to list out each individual element of the array in the admin area and delete a value from that array.

I currently loop over each of my array elements and attempt to use ajax to delete them, when I click on the delete button it sends the value to my ajax action, I then load the post meta I want, remove the value and then update the post meta. However my console.log(data) brings back 0 every time and doesn't fade the div. Can anyone see why?

```
function print_pdfs_attached() {

    global $post;

    $attached_pdfs = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pdf_upload_url', true ); ?>

    <p>All PDFs attached to the article</p>

    <?php
    $i=0;
    if($attached_pdfs) { 
        foreach($attached_pdfs as $pdf) { ?>
            <div id=<?php echo $pdf; ?>>

                <p><?php echo $pdf; ?></p>

                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pdf; ?>" id="ajaxtestdel_postid<?php echo $i ?>">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><label for="del">delete</label></th>
                    <td><input type="button" name="del" id="del<?php echo $i; ?>" value="delete" class="button"></td>
                </tr>
                <script>
                  jQuery('#del<?php echo $i; ?>').on('click', function(){
                    var post = jQuery('#ajaxtestdel_postid<?php echo $i ?>').val(); // get post id from hidded field
                    console.log(post);
                    jQuery.ajax({
                      url: 'admin-ajax.php', // in backend you should pass the ajax url using this variable
                      type: 'POST',
                      data: { action : 'ajaxtestdel', postid: post },
                      success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        jQuery("#<?php echo $pdf; ?>").fadeOut( "slow" );
                      }
                    });
                  });
                </script>
             <?php
             $i++; 
             ?>
         </div>
         <?php
        } 
    }
    else { ?>
        <p>No PDFs are currently attached to this article</p> <?php
    }
}

function ajaxtestdel(){
    global $post;

    $currentPdfs = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pdf_upload_url', true );
    $postValue = isset($_POST['postid']) ? $_POST['postid'] : '';
    $array_without_strawberries = array_diff($currentPdfs, array($postValue));
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pdf_upload_url', $array_without_strawberries );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxtestdel', 'ajaxtestdel');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing anything from the AJAX callback. Trying using [wp_send_json_success](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success):

```
function ajaxtestdel(){
    global $post;
    $currentPdfs = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pdf_upload_url', true );
    $postValue = isset($_POST['postid']) ? $_POST['postid'] : '';
    $array_without_strawberries = array_diff($currentPdfs, array($postValue));
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pdf_upload_url', $array_without_strawberries );

    // Send something back to AJAX
    wp_send_json_success();
}
```

I have a feeling that perhaps your jQuery selector is incorrect for the fadeout - `jQuery("#<?php echo $pdf; ?>")` what is `$pdf` is it a valid id name?

Hope this helps!